# FuelPHP how to load model in test? and how to load and test controller?

Tags: fuelphp

how to load model in test? and how to load and test controller ?

Fatal Error : Model Not Found!

this works in the controller: #but does not work in the test

```php
<?php

# PATH app\modules\adm\classes\model

namespace Adm\Model;

class Medico extends \Orm\Model
{
  protected static  $_primary_key = array('id');
  protected static  $_table_name  = 'medico';
}

# PATH app\modules\adm\classes\controller
# WORKS!!!
namespace Adm;

use Adm\Model\Medico; # <- WORKS!!!

class Controller_Medicos extends \Controller_Template
{ 
  public function action_index()
  {
    $data['medicos'] = Medico::find()->select('id','segundo_nome')->limit(1)->get_one();

    print_r($data['medicos']->segundo_nome);

    $this->template->content = \View::forge('medicos/index');
  }
}

# app\modules\tests\adm\classes\model
# DOES NOT WORK!!

namespace Adm;
use Adm\Model\Medico; # <- Adm\Model\Medico NOT FOUND why ?
class Test_Model_Medico extends \TestCase
{
  public function test_autocomplete()
  {
    $medico = Medico::find(1);

    $this->assertEquals(2,2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the module path to phpunit.xml as shown in the documentation http://fueldevdocs.exite.eu/general/unit_testing.html#unit_tests_for_modules ?

Answer (score 1):

When you request the controller through the URL, the routing engine will autoload the module.

This does not happen when you run tests through oil, so you to load it manually in the setup section of your test class:

```
\Module::load('adm');
```